# try to add platform then getting "Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@~6.2.2"

Tags: cordova, ionic3

**cordova platform add android --save**

```
    ? Running command - failed!**

    [ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
            You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.

    [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova platform add android --save(exit code 1):

            **Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~6.2.2
            Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-android@~6.2.2**
            Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is icorrect.
            Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
            Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT
```

Comment: are you behind a proxy? are you using any antivirus?

Comment: no behind a proxy or any antivirus

Comment: which node/npm versions are you using? can you try with `cordova platform add android --save --nofetch`?

Comment: Node :: 6.10.3 and npm :: 5.0.1

Comment: We try to cordova platform add android --save --nofetch command and installed platform

Comment: version detail below       global packages:
    @ionic/cli-utils : 1.3.0
    Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1
    Ionic CLI        : 3.3.0
local packages:
    @ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
    @ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.3.0
    @ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.0
    Cordova Platforms               : android broken
    Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.3.0

System:
    Node       : v6.10.3
    OS         : Windows 8.1
    Xcode      : not installed
    ios-deploy : not installed
    ios-sim    : not installed

Comment: Cordova Platforms  : android broken  so it's not run in emulator

Comment: now getting this error   [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova build android (exit code 1):

        ANDROID_HOME=E:\ADK\android-sdk-windows
        JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
        Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT

Comment: Node 6 brings npm 3, npm 5 just came out, so maybe it's not fully compatible with Cordova

Comment: Now this error occur, cordova run android
ANDROID_HOME=E:\ADK\android-sdk-windows
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code ENOENT


[ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
        You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above dir

[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova run android (exit code 1)

Comment: Yuppp..Resolved error by add path variable "C:\Windows\System32"

Comment: @Vishal which path did you added to solve this problem.I am also facing this problem.

Comment: In user variable/system variable in environment variable set path = "C:\Windows\System32"

Answer (score 1):

In user variable/system variable in environment variable set path = "C:\Windows\System32"